# Lighting problem of faces

Tags: light, faces, lighting

I've created a building model with a architecture software (Sweet Home 3D) and on the generated .obj object I have this problem: the flat walls are divided around windows and doors and look curved or angled. It appears that the 3D is flat though, so maybe it is a lighting or a normal problem?

[image: the preview in SW3D and how it should look like]

[image: the ojb model imported in Blender]

Does anyone know how to solve this in blender so the walls look flat?

Many thanks

Thomas.

Comment: Don't use *shade smooth*, use shade flat, or enable Object data > Normals  Autosmooth in the properties window. Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/shading.html?highlight=shade%20smooth